# Algorithms: Recurrence relations from CLRS

Tags: algorithm

I was recently trying to solve some recurrence relations from CLRS and I noticed a strange nuance while solving these equations. I don't know if any of you guys have noticed it or not or may be the Theory champs can throw more light on this. (I too have a degree in CS but not in Theory!). While solving the recurrence for the master theorem:

T(n) = a T(n/b) + f(n)

I noticed that the reasoning goes something like this:

i) expand the a-ary recursion tree and we get a<sup>log<sub>b</sub> n</sup> leaf nodes where the work done per node is Θ(1), giving Θ(n<sup>log<sub>b</sub> a</sup>) for all leaf nodes

ii) for all the non leaf nodes, g(n) = Σ a<sup>j</sup> f(b/n<sup>j</sup>) where j sums from 0 to floor (log<sub>b</sub> n - 1), where height of the tree is log<sub>b</sub> n

iii) Now take a leap of faith: make a claim that f(n) is really bounded by O(n<sup>log<sub>b</sub> a</sup> - ε) for some ε > 0

iv) Now solve g(n) in terms of f(n) and solve T(n) in terms of g(n). As mentioned in step i, T(n) is really  Θ(n<sup>log<sub>b</sub> a</sup>) + g(n), so once you have some g(n) combine with the other term to come up with T(n)

The trouble I am having with this approach is that here the reasoning is something like this: look, if we assume the right hand side to be X, then we plug that into the equation to solve the left hand side. Isn't this reasoning a little bizarre? Isn't it something like this:

Given: X<sup>2</sup> = 8X - 16

so let us assume X=4 and put that into the RHS and solve for X, cool, see, we got 4!!!
This is definitely interesting but are you really solving the problem - why didn't you guess X to be an irrational number, why not an imaginary number?

Moreover, I would actually like to know as to in which branch of Mathematics this type of reasoning exists as I suspect it has come to CS from that field. Any idea? I know that almost 99% of the Math in CS are just "some fancier form of arguments under certain assumptions" (as CS majors don't solve equations in the conventional sense), but still this method seems very unique. Any idea?

Comment: There's a typo in ii), it should be g(n) = Σ a^j f(n/b^j).

Answer (score 2):

The funny leap-of-faith step is a shortcut for mathematical induction.  Basically, it goes like so:

- Check that the assumption is true for some base case (e.g. only one non-leaf node).
- Given that it is true for the `n`th non-base case, make sure it is true for the `n+1`st non-base case.

You can usually shortcut this by just assuming that what you want to prove is true, plugging it in, and showing that it works.  Whether this is the case in this particular instance, I can't quite tell.

There is often a bit of inspiration involved in solving these sorts of problems, since you have to pick out the right form for the recurrence in order to get the induction step to work, but it's not usually picking things out of thin air; in this case, it's picking things out of very thick air that arises from careful examination of the relationship between the leaf nodes and the others.